# Disable pagination in boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

Is it possible to disable pagination in boto ?

The CLI mentions that I can disable paginations, for example in listing datapipelines, It says - >  `You can disable pagination by providing the --no-paginate argument` - [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/list-pipelines.html)

However, when I look at datapipelines boto docs, I can't find any place to disable pagination. I am working with someone else's code who did not read api docs and assumed everythign was non paginated, and it would be easier to just turn on no pagination . Thanks for the help !

Specifically, I want to turn [list_pipelines](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/datapipeline.html#DataPipeline.Client.list_pipelines) into no paginated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so It turns out that boto does not let you currently disable pagination. It is not Opt in . I tried running it with and without pagination and I always get incomplete answers without pagination.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI paginates by default, but in boto3 you have to opt-in by making a call to `get_paginator` or manually paginating. So you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the info, its not clear at all from the list_pipelines. Can you please point me to where you got this from ?

Comment: There's information about the CLI's pagination [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/pagination.html). For botocore / boto3 it's never explicitly mentioned that it doesn't handle pagination by default, but it is implied by the contract of a low level interface as well as the existence of a separate function to handle pagination for you. You can review the code on GitHub if you'd like to make extra sure: [CLI](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli), [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore), [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3)

Comment: Also, docs for the list_pipelines paginator: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/datapipeline.html#DataPipeline.Paginator.ListPipelines